# How to filter out night hours in Kibana (Elasitic)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to see Exception counts in Kibana, but I'm only interest in working hours. So I want to skip e.g. from 00:00 to 05:00 (or to show e.g. 05:00 to 21:00). I know how to filter individual days, but that doesn't scale to multiple days. E.g. I want to see last 14 days and skip night hours in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use elasticsearch [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) enrich your data add a new field for hour and filter by it. I'm sharing the step with an example.

###### * add an ingest pipeline and get the hours and save it as a new field with the following ingest pipeline https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/date_to_hour
{
  "description": "Extract hour from timestamp using Grok",
  "processors": [
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "patterns": ["%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}T%{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

###### * add the ingest pipeline to the index as default pipeline

```
PUT day_and_night
{"settings":{"index.default_pipeline":"date_to_hour"}}
```

###### ** use the following if the index exist

```
PUT day_and_night/_settings
{"index.default_pipeline":"date_to_hour"}
```

###### add the data

```
POST day_and_night/_bulk
{"index": {}}
{"field": "value1", "timestamp": "2024-01-22T02:00:00"}
{"index": {}}
{"field": "value2", "timestamp": "2024-01-22T04:00:00"}
{"index": {}}
{"field": "value3", "timestamp": "2024-01-22T06:00:00"}
{"index": {}}
{"field": "value4", "timestamp": "2024-01-22T09:00:00"}
{"index": {}}
{"field": "value5", "timestamp": "2024-01-22T20:00:00"}
{"index": {}}
{"field": "value6", "timestamp": "2024-01-22T22:00:00"}
```

###### search all the data - 6hits

```
POST day_and_night/_search
```

###### add an alias to search only between 5 to 21.

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "day_and_night",
        "alias": "work_hours",
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "hour": {
              "gte": "05",
              "lte": "21"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

###### search with the alias name

```
GET work_hours/_search
```

#Results:

```
GET day_and_night/_count
  "count": 6

GET work_hours/_count
  "count": 3
```

[image]